# can't store the value to variable from the class

Tags: php, class

I'm trying to store the value from the class below as a variable, so i could used it later on, but I can't get it working.

Any ideas?

```
class Dates {


    public function __construct($date) {
    $this->DateCompare($date);
    }
    public function DateCompare($date) {
        $date1 = new DateTime("2015-04-08");
        $date2 = new DateTime($date);
        $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
        return $diff->format("%a");

    }
}

echo $test = new Dates("2015-05-04");
```

Error I'm getting: *Catchable fatal error: Object of class Dates could not be converted to string in /virtual/index.php*

As said before, I don't want to echo that out, just store it in the `$test` variable, but if I can't even echo that out, then I'm not storing it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing a class constructor can return [directly or indirectly] is itself.

```
public static function instance() { return new self(); }
```

Add the above line and then get rid of the constructor.
Replace the echo call with:

```
$test = Dates::instance() -> DateCompare("2015-05-04");

echo $test;
```

Explanation: your initial code, was trying to `echo` an instance of the `Dates` Object, the return you had was ignored because a new Class ***ALWAYS HAS TO Return ITSELF***
Actually the return you had got dumped, since it was returned back to the constructor but didn't go anywhere from there.

An alternative, if you were planning to Echo it; would be to add a `__tostring()` function which would get triggered when you try to echo the `Class Instance Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Class constructors cannot return anything - apart from the new class they have just created. Objects can't be echoed. Try either var_dump() or try adding a [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method in the class:

```
public function __toString(){return 'something useful';}
```